# Golang - Filtering Stdout of Active SSH Session

Tags: session, go, networking, ssh, network-programming

I'm writing an SSH client in Go that connects to a switch and runs a list of configuration commands. So far, I am able to successfully connect to a switch, run the desired commands, and print the output of the session. The problem comes when the switch is expecting a `\n`, space, or "q" to be entered when a command's output is too long. For example:

```
switch#show int status

Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi1/0/1                      notconnect   100          auto   auto 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/2                      connected    915        a-full  a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/3                      notconnect   100          auto   auto 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/4                      notconnect   100          auto   auto 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi1/0/5                      notconnect   230          auto   auto 10/100/1000BaseTX
...
Po1       sw-sww-100-sww-0-0 connected    trunk      a-full    10G
 --More-- # Program hangs here; expecting a new line, space, or 'q'
```

The `--More--` prompt is not actually printed to the screen, so simply checking if the current line of `Stdout` contains `--More--` and sending a `\n`, space, or "q" does not work.

[image: Gif of <code>--More--</code> prompt disappearing.]

In addition to fixing this problem, I'd like to filter `Stdout` of the session so that the only thing printed is the output of each command. In other words, I don't want the switch's prompt to be printed to the terminal.

To sum up:

1. How to capture and print *only* the output of each command?
2. How to send a new line, space, or letter "q" when prompted?

Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type Device struct {
    Config  *ssh.ClientConfig
    Client  *ssh.Client
    Session *ssh.Session
    Stdin   io.WriteCloser
    Stdout  io.Reader
    Stderr  io.Reader
}

func (d *Device) Connect() error {
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", os.Args[1]+":22", d.Config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    sshIn, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    sshOut, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    sshErr, err := session.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    d.Client = client
    d.Session = session
    d.Stdin = sshIn
    d.Stdout = sshOut
    d.Stderr = sshErr
    return nil
}

func (d *Device) SendCommand(cmd string) error {
    if _, err := io.WriteString(d.Stdin, cmd+"\r\n"); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (d *Device) SendConfigSet(cmds []string) error {
    for _, cmd := range cmds {
        if _, err := io.WriteString(d.Stdin, cmd+"\r\n"); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    return nil
}

func (d *Device) PrintOutput() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(d.Stdout)
    for {
        text, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Printf("%s", text)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
}

func (d *Device) PrintErr() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(d.Stderr)
    for {
        text, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Printf("%s", text)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    sshConf := ssh.Config{}
    sshConf.Ciphers = append(sshConf.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc", "3des-cbc", "blowfish-cbc", "arcfour")
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        Config: sshConf,
        User:   "mwalto7",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password("Lion$Tiger$Bear$"),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Timeout:         time.Second * 5,
    }

    sw := &Device{Config: config}

    fmt.Println("Connecting to ", os.Args[1])
    if err := sw.Connect(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer sw.Client.Close()
    defer sw.Session.Close()
    defer sw.Stdin.Close()

    if err := sw.Session.Shell(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    commands := []string{"show int status", "exit"}
    if err := sw.SendConfigSet(commands); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    sw.Session.Wait()

    sw.PrintOutput()
    sw.PrintErr()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `--More--` isn't printed. How does the user know to input something? As an aside, does this device not have some method to script commands, or at least turn off interactive input?

Comment: @JimB The `--More--` prompt is not found in the `Stdout` and is not printed to the screen. Once you press enter or space enough times to view the entire output of a command, the prompt is just gone.

Comment: @JimB I added a gif of the prompt.

Comment: The program probably directs its output through the command `more`. Does it really wait for input when you are not running the program on the consol?

Comment: You should be able to hack the TTY settings in the [RequestPty](https://sourcegraph.com/-/godoc/refs?def=Session%2FRequestPty&pkg=golang.org%2Fx%2Fcrypto%2Fssh&repo=golang.org%2Fx%2Fcrypto) method to turn off ECHO (#1) and request a bigger terminal size to prevent the need for entering `q` (#2). That being said, SNMP is probably better suited for what you need to do, give it another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by sending the command `terminal length 0` just after connecting to the switch, before sending the rest of the commands. This disabled the `—More—` prompt by setting the switch’s terminal height to 0, allowing the whole output of a command to be displayed.